# Struggling to find array in Jekyll config file (site navigation)

Tags: yaml, jekyll

In my `_config.yml` I have:

```
navigation:
- text: Home
  url: index.html
- text: About
  url: about.html
- text: Blog
  url: blog.html
- text: Portfolio
  url: portfolio.html
```

In my `default.html` layout I have:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
  {% for link in site.navigation %}
    {% assign current = nil %}
    {% if page.url == link.url %}
      {% assign current = 'current' %}
    {% endif %}

    <li class="nav-list-item{% if forloop.first %}first{% endif %} {{ current }} {% if forloop.last %}nav-list-item-last{% endif %}">
      <a class="{{ current }}" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

For some reason, this is not working. Why might this be?

Comment: It works for me. Excepting the marking of current page as `page.url` contains path, like “/index.html”, so equality checks will fail. How is not working for you? Absolutely no output? Uninterpreted Liquid in output? Just not marking the current item?

Comment: It can't seem to find `site.navigation` at all. If I completely empty the contents of `_config.yml` and just input the above, that's the set up I currently have.

Comment: May not be relevant, but are you trying this locally or on GitHub? (I only tested locally.) Can you access other settings from your _config.yml? Are you sure the navigation array's items are indented with spaces, not tabs?

Comment: I'm testing it locally. They are definitely spaces. Odd :/ Do I need to nest `navigation` under `site` or does Jekyll do this intelligently?

Comment: What do you mean by “nest”? But the answer is probably no, as your code works for me as you posted: in _config.yml you specify just navigation, in the Liquid template you reference it as `{{ site.navigation }}`. By the way, it is not expanded to anything neither this way, without the loop?

Comment: Well, I reference `site.navigation` but in `_config.yml` it is just `navigation`. Sorry but what do you mean by 'it is not expanded to anything neither this way?'

Comment: I mean when I put `{{ site.navigation }}` in the template file I get “{"text"=>"Home", "url"=>"index.html"}{"text"=>"About", "url"=>"about.html"}{"text"=>"Blog", "url"=>"blog.html"}{"text"=>"Portfolio", "url"=>"portfolio.html"}” in the output file.

Comment: Ahh, fixed it! I didn't realise Jekyll didn't restart when you made changes to `_config.yml`, as it does with all other files. So it was just me being silly!

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the update. Definitely widens my debugging skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out you have to restart the server and run `jekyll --server` again and the `_config.yml` variables will be accessible.

Then after figuring it out came back to this page and was about to post this answer, clicked `add / show 4 more comments` and saw that this was also found out by the op. So posting it as answer.

Comment: Thanks. Should've posted it as an answer myself, oops!

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I forgive you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer: You can - as you mentioned in your answer - use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to end the currently running server (in your CLI). **But**, you can as well start the server with

```
jekyll server -w
```

to tell Jekyll to watch for changes in your files. Whilst this won't work for changes to the `_config.yml`, it works for all other files. Note, that this won't work including the `--safe` option, so you won't get errors. To catch them, I still recommend to run `jekyll --safe build` from time to time to see if you got syntax errors. The same goes for running `jekyll doctor`/`jekyll hyde` sometimes during your dev process.